# How to make a dynamically-sized double-int array?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I am trying to make a generic matrix struct in C++ but right now all I've got is

```
struct matrix{
    int cells[dim][dim];
}
```

where dim is a const int.

However I wish to make things a little more dynamic so I can declare matrices of different sizes. I can get around this issue by converting everything to vectors of int vectors, but then I suffer a massive speed loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can get around this issue by converting everything to vectors of int vectors, but then I suffer a massive speed loss.

FAUX. **That's just wrong.** `std::vector` is almost as fast as raw arrays. **Do use `vector<vector<int> >`.**

---

However, if you still insist on raw arrays:

```
int **p = new int *[rows];
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    p[i] = new int[columns];
```

Freeing:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    delete [] p[i];

delete [] p;
```

Comment: I am building this matrix class for some online-judge websites. My vector<vector <int> > implementation failed every single time, but my array one works and hits the time limit consistently.

Comment: @AgainstASicilian I suspect you are misusing the vector... Memory allocation is slow, so you should do that as rarely as possible (which may not be obvious if you don't know that you can `resize()` the vector), but accessing the elements is almost as fast as in the case of raw arrays.

Comment: I don't believe I'm misusing it in any way; the implementation is literally almost the same in both cases, except in one I am using the struct and in the other I am just using raw vector<vector<int> >. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian As I stated, you should not be `pushing_back()` (and the like) elements, because that does reallocation. `resize()` and `operator[]` should do the job.

Comment: I'm not pushing back any elements. What I do is I declare the size of the matrix by doing vector<vector<int> > matrix(len1, vector<int>(len2)) so I don't have to push anything back

Comment: @AgainstASicilian I just ran a quick benchmark with 100 million elements, and it ran in 1 second using raw arrays and in 3 seconds with vectors when I used `-O0`. That's not bad.

Comment: I suppose the time difference matters for online judges at least; my vector implementation never passed

Comment: @AgainstASicilian I *still* feel that in this case, you are on the razor's edge. If a 3-fold difference matters, then your accepted solution only **almost** passed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the fact that `std::vector` is just as fast as a raw array, does not imply that a vector of vectors is comparable to a two-dimensional array.  It's more comparable to an array of pointers to arrays, which is considerably slower than a true contiguous two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a single vector for matrix class which works pretty well since the data will be sequential depending on row or column based storage.  For example

```
Struct Matrix {
    std::vector<int> cells;
    int nrows, ncols;

    Matrix(int rows, int cols) : cells(rows * cols), nrows(rows), ncols(cols) 
    {}

    int& operator()(int row, int col){
        return cells[row * ncols + col];
    }

    void resize(int rows, int cols){
        cells.resize(rows*cols);
        nrows = rows; 
        ncols = cols;
    }
}
```

This is a nice vector wrapper for a matrix that avoids you needing to use c-style things.

Comment: typo in `operator()`, you should use the `col` parameter somewhere.  Also in resize, you should save the new dimensions.

Comment: I agree about resize, but unless you want to add an assert that cols > ncols and rows > nrows I think that it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'd always go with a flat vector (pre-reserved/sized) or Boost MultiArray.

However, what's wrong with a template?

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M=N>
struct matrix {
    typedef T row_type[M];
    row_type cells[N];

    row_type*       begin()       { return std::begin(cells); }
    row_type*       end()         { return std::end(cells);   }
    row_type const* begin() const { return std::begin(cells); }
    row_type const* end()   const { return std::end(cells);   }
};
```

Or even better, with `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M=N>
struct matrix {
    typedef std::array<T, M> row_type;
    std::array<row_type, N> cells;

    row_type*       begin()       { return cells.begin(); }
    row_type*       end()         { return cells.end();   }
    row_type const* begin() const { return cells.begin(); }
    row_type const* end()   const { return cells.end();   }
};
```

Just a cheesy demo to show it's genericity: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4522b2959a9f4f4bcbe457aa6f4fb5ed-16ccd8065d089fe1982fc39c3a92e82f)**

```
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t N, typename T=int>
T test()
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    typedef matrix<T, N, N*3+2> Mtx;
    Mtx the_matrix;

    size_t next_gen {};
    auto gen = [&](){ return next_gen++ * 3.14; };

    for(auto& row : the_matrix)
        std::generate(begin(row), end(row), gen);

    return std::accumulate(
            begin(the_matrix), end(the_matrix), T{},  
            [](T accum, typename Mtx::row_type& row) 
            { 
                return accum + std::accumulate(begin(row), end(row), T{}); 
            });
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << test<3, int>()    << "\n";
    std::cout << test<3, double>() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a template is that template arguments aren't dynamically settable.  BTW there's already a deleted answer suggesting it.

Comment: That's not wrong, because it wasn't a requirement in the first place?

Comment: I guess it's possible he's misusing the term *dynamic*.  In which case we should vote to undelete whale's answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt I thought the phrase "so I can declare matrices of different sizes" was sufficiently exact. (_Also re: undelete: We could. However, there's no guessing as to why that answer was actually deleted (I hadn't spotted it, either_)

Comment: He also talks about online judges, which often give the problem size as the first line on `stdin`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why are we using crystal balls? I'm responding to the question.